# Bootprocess of Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: boot, systemd, init, init.d

I'm trying to figure out, what the system does during its boot procedure.

This is how far I came:

1. `GRUB` (bootloader) → Kernel → `systemd` (init process)
2. `systemd` checks default bootlevel/target (*where?*)
3. `systemd` runs scripts from appropriate folder in `/etc/rcX.d`

   - `/etc/rcX.d` is a kind of sorting of the files in `/etc/init.d`.
   - Apps in `/etc/init.d`, that need a conf, put it in `/etc/init` (?)
   - When does `/etc/rcS.d` get used?
4. `/etc/rc.local` gets started (although debian FAQ advises not to use it)
5. [what else comes here?]

Question: Can someone fill in the blanks and correct false information?

Comment: `/etc/rcX.d`, `/etc/init.d`, `/etc/rc.local`, and the entire concept of bootlevel/runlevel are legacies of a much older init (sysvinit), that Ubuntu moved away from many years ago. Systemd provides a compatibility layer for older applications to still function...but new scripts should really use the appropriate systemd *target*, which provides finer control over the conditions and dependencies for controlling your software.

Comment: As of my understanding the *targets* from systemd function essentially as runlevels. Just with a finer control and a different name.

Comment: Perhaps, perhaps not. To me, runlevels and targets seem very, very different.

Answer (score 1):

I try to fill in the blanks through the answeres given in #ubuntu-offtopic @ freenode

1. `GRUB` (bootloader) → Kernel → `systemd` (init process)
2. `systemd` checks default `target` (roughly a new term for `runlevel`, but a little more finegrained)

   - Place: somewhere within the management files of systemd
   - `systemctl get-default` shows you the your default target
3. `systemd` starts to run services. This is basically the same task as running scripts in `/etc/rc*.d`

   - Init scripts are located under `/etc/systemd/system` (`*.target.wants`)
   - If a service should start, but there's no `*.service` file for it, systemd check which runlevel the current target would correspond to and runs the appropriate init script from `etc/rc*.d`. More infos can be found under `man systemd.service`
   - @`/etc/rcS.d`: This seems to be a runlevel, just like the numbers. 'S' *might* stand for "Single user mode" - like the rescue console...
   - I really advice to read `man systemd.service` (5). It has a lot of useful information with even more useful pointers to the various topics.
4. `/etc/rc.local` gets started (although debian FAQ advises not to use it)
5. GUI, like the login screen, is just another service started through `/etc/systemd/system` from step 3

### Misc information:

- `/etc/rc*.d` and `/etc/init.d` is the traditional way of initializing, that SysV did. As described, it's still supported. Though, it *might* become unsupported one day, if everything migrated to systemd (whether this is good or bad).
- Files in `/etc/init` are used by `upstart`, which is (as far as I know) not used in Ubuntu (because systemd does its job)

### Related topics:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_boot_process
- https://www.linuxnix.com/how-login-process-work-in-linux/